# Autosys dependent job status check

Tags: bash, shell-script, autosys

I am writing shell script to get the status of autosys job.

[image]

I am able to awk the ST column using below command

```
autorep -J ${JOB_NAME} -d -L0 | awk '/${ST} /{print $6}'
```

Now I want to get the status of dependent jobs for that i have to use job_depends command to get the list of dependent jobs and check the status for each job using autorep command, need help over here.

[image]

```
Job Name                                                         Status/Exec. Mode    Date Cond?           Start Cond?     Dep. Cond?
--------                                                         -----------------    ------------         -----------     ----------
170251_MSTR_FII_UAT_ISERVER_STOP                                 SUCCESS              No                   No              Yes      

  Dependent Job Name                                                            Condition
   ------------------                                                            ---------
   170251_MSTR_FII_UAT_ISERVER2_STOP                                             SUCCESS(170251_MSTR_FII_UAT_ISERVER_STOP)
```

Comment: Please replace all images with its text.

Comment: I have managed to update the text output